# List Row 1 data (Headers) into Column in another Sheet and Create HyperLink

Tags: excel, vba

I failed to find the macro to achieve my goal,Now I have exhausted to my searching ability.

I have two Worksheets
1 - DataSheet
2 - AllHeaders

I want macro to copy Row 1 data from worksheet "DataSheet", transpose it and paste this into worksheet "AllHeaders" and create hyperlink to that Headers.
Than you!

Here is recorded macro but i have recorded just two column header hyperlink as there are thousands of headers manually it takes day to complete this.

```
  Sub Macro1()
 '
 ' Macro1 Macro
 '

 '
Range("A1").Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select
Range("A1").Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select
Selection.Copy
Sheets("AllHeaders").Select
Range("B5").Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=True
Range("B5").Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
ActiveSheet.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=Selection, Address:="", SubAddress:= _
    "DataSheet!A1", TextToDisplay:="responseid"
Range("B6").Select
ActiveSheet.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=Selection, Address:="", SubAddress:= _
    "DataSheet!B1", TextToDisplay:="respid"
End Sub
```

Comment: Have you tried recording a macro and using that as a starting point?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try doing this in a loop. I am not able to test this at the moment, but it should be most of what you need:

```
Sub CreateHeaders()
    Dim wsData as Worksheet
    Dim wsHeaders as Worksheet
    Dim headerRange as Range
    Dim header as Range
    Dim i as Long: i=0
    Dim anchor as Range
    DIm subAddr as String

    Set wsData = Worksheets("DataSheet")
    Set wsHeaders = Worksheets("AllHeaders")
    Set headerRange = wsData.Range("A1", wsData.Range("A1").End(xlToRight))
    Set anchor = wsHeaders.Range("B5")  '## begin inserting the hyperlinks at B5

    For each header in headerRange  '## iterate over each cell in the header row
        subAddr = "'" & wsData.Name & "'!" & header.Address
        With wsHeaders
            .Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=anchor, Address:="", SubAddress:= _
                 subAddr, TextToDisplay:=header.Value
        End With
        i = i+1  
        Set anchor = anchor.Offset(i,0)  '## increment the location of the next hyperlink, to the next row
    Next

End Sub
```

Comment: I ran the macro and got this 1) Didn't transpose the header in "AllHeaders" worksheets, though copied header after certain blank columns in one row, 2) hyperlink did not link with "Datasheet" worksheet.it got linked with the "AllHeaders" worsksheet.

Comment: I made some revisions. That should now transpose so that all headers will be in column B, beginning at `B5`.  Also, I think I made a revision to make the link to `DataSheet` worksheet.

Comment: Hyperlink worked well but transposed all the headers after blank rows interval, rows are incrementing. 1st header started from B5 but 3rd pasted after one blank row and it is inrementing...

Comment: Change it to `Set anchor = anchor.offset(1, 0)` instead of `Set anchor = anchot.offset(i,  0)`..